# How is the +literal implemented in python?

Tags: python

In the Python interactive prompt (I am on 3.9.10), writing something like `x = +88.9` is valid and gives `x` as `88.9`.

From my tests, this seems to be the case with all the literals. Why and how is this implemented? Is there some subroutine for the `__add__` method or just a way literals are stored in Python?

Comment: Not `__add__`; it is [the `__pos__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pos__), which by default returns the same object.

Comment: What tests were you running? Example code and results could be useful if it improves the clarity of the question.